# Setting a fluid content width

Tags: theme-development

I'm thinking about setting the content width theme feature in my theme's functions.php file using:

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 600;
}
```

My understanding is this will set the max allowed width for any text and images in my theme.

My layout is rather fluid (I don't have a fixed width) so would like to use a percentage value. How can I set the max content width to 100%?

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$content_width`](https://developer.wordpress.com/themes/content-width/) is a global variable that can indeed be used by themes and plugins to set a maximum width on content elements. Therefore it's always a fixed value in pixels. The plugins don't know about your `css`.

However, this does not limit your possibilities in your theme. You can still set image sizes larger than `$content_width` and use them. Keeping the theme fluid is a matter of `css`.

The thing you'll find is that embeds (amongst others) use `$content_width` to determine their max width. So make sure that it is larger than the max column in your site if you want it to fit neatly.